# How can I maximize a and r in a geometric sequence given the sum

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to divide a line into 5 sections for an art project. The line is 65 units long and I want the sections to be a geometric sequence rounded to the nearest unit. The math side of me wants to find an exact solution first.

That is I want $a+ar+ar^2+a^3+ar^4=65$. How can I maximize $a$ and $r$?

I tried using the closed form $a(1-r^5)/(1-r)=65$ taking the derivative w.r.t. $r$ but ended up just getting $ar^4=13$, which clearly can't be the correct solution if I want all the other terms to be less than $ar^4$. I also tried google-ing but everything I see shows either $r$ or $a$ is given in the problem. Thanks.

Comment: We need to maximize $ar$ or $a,r$ separately

Answer (score 2):

You have one constraint, decide on what function of $a,r$ you want to maximize, use the constraint to solve for $a$ and plug in. For example, to maximize $ar$, note that
$$
a = \frac{65(1-r)}{1-r^5}
$$
so you want to maximize
$$
ar = \frac{65r(1-r)}{1-r^5} = g(r),
$$
and now standard Calculus techniques apply, here is the [solution from Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize+65r(1-r)%2F(1-r%5E5)).

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking it was some simple algebraic part I was missing and it turns out it was!